# Does the tensor product of a finitely presented module and a flat module always finitely presented?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

If M is an R-module which admits a  degreewise finite projective resolution (i.e.,  a projective resolution P of M such that each Pi in P is finitely generated projective) and N a flat R-module, does the tensor product of M and N always finitely presented? Thanks!

Comment: No, e.g. an infinitely generated free module is flat.

Comment: If R is a Noetherian ring, is the result true? Many thnaks!

Comment: No. You can take $M$ to be a finitely generated free module and $N$ to be an infinitely generated free module. This counterexample works over any ring.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: if f is a ring homomorphism from R to S such that S is a flat R-module and M admits a degreewise finite projective resolution, N is any flat S-module, does S tensor M  tensor N admits a degreewise finite S-projective resolution? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user94423 Comments should be used for discussing the question at hand, not an entirely new question. How about you ask a new question?